# Plist format not rendering in rails action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to render a plist format in an action.

I have installed plist gem.Added Mime Type to the environment.rb `Mime::Type.register "application/plist", :plist`.

I have rendered it like

```
  respond_to do |format|
       format.plist {render :plist => @test_object.to_plist }
    end
```

But I am getting `Template is missing, Missing template path.erb`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need a plist.erb template in your views folder similar to [here](https://github.com/chef-osx/xcode/blob/master/templates/default/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist.erb).